# Gradlew > Invalid TLS padding data

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradlew, jdk1.7

I'm moving an Android build job over from a SLED 11 SP2 machine to Ubuntu 14.04. On Ubuntu I've installed java version "1.7.0_71" and use gradlew version 2.14.1.

But intermiddently during the build I get the following error.

```
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.3/gradle-core-2.1.3.jar
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'jabber-android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.1.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.3/gradle-core-2.1.3.jar'.
         > Invalid TLS padding data
```

When googling for a solution I saw lots of reference to Java encryption code. But one post did sound similar to my issue.

https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?528-How-to-fix-intermittent-HTTP-SSL-failure-(padding-exception)

However it says this problem was fixed in Java 7 update 67. i.e. I should have the fix.

After this issue repeated on a build machine I remoted onto it. The first time I ran the command directly the error appeared. I then ran grandle with

```
gradlew --stacktrace --info
```

which did not reproduce the problem. Nor did removing those flags cause the issue to re-appear. When I ran the build job it passed.

Has anyone else come across this problem? How can I resolve it?

**Update:**

After testing it I only see this problem when using

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

If I switch over to

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I cannot reproduce the issue above. i.e. In build.gradle

**Update:**

I've updated the machine with JDK version 1.8.0_111-b14. I'm still get an error but it's now reported as

```
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/neenbedankt/gradle/plugins/android-apt/1.8/android-apt-1.8.jar
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.3/gradle-core-2.1.3.jar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'jabber-android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.1.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/2.1.3/gradle-core-2.1.3.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
```